# How does the map() run in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to find how `map()` runs in Python and read its output, so that I tried some codes like the below. But I can't understand yet about `map object` and the flow of data from `input()` to `print()`.

- Codes

```
def details(txt) :
    print("elements :", txt)
    print("type :", type(txt))
    try :
        print("elements' type :", type(txt[0]), "\n")
    except :
        print("elements' type : an error occurs.\n")

txt = "1 2 3 4 5"
details(txt)

txtsplit = txt.split()
details(txtsplit)

txtmap = map(int, txt.split())
details(txtmap) # an error occurs

txtlist = list(txtmap)
details(txtlist)
```

- Results

```
elements : 1 2 3 4 5
type : <class 'str'>
elements' type : <class 'str'>

elements : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
type : <class 'list'>
elements' type : <class 'str'>

elements : <map object at 0x7fefcdfe8dc0>
type : <class 'map'>
elements' type : an error occurs.

elements : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
type : <class 'list'>
elements' type : <class 'int'>
```

Is there some way to read the original figure of the `map object`?

I know the common use of combination with `list()`, so hope to emphasize that my question is neither about its grammarical usage nor about solving the error.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: A `map` isn't a list. It is a generator type object. I don't know what you mean by "read the original figure of the map object". They don't contain a hidden list but instead provides the elements when needed. It is typical of how Python 3 approaches iteration.

Comment: As John said, a `map` is a generator. They are evaluated lazily, and don't yield their contents unless they are explicitly asked to (iterating over them, unpacking or consuming their contents to construct a concrete collection like a list or tuple).

Comment: I've found this comprehensive article by typing "python map" in google. https://realpython.com/python-map-function/#getting-started-with-pythons-map

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I guessed that `txtmap` has had already some values when I declared it. But, actually it has not contained any values yet and been just ready to call values iteratively before I request like the way of `list()`, right? I will also refer the url that you suggested!